# Can I fillin an array in a form

Tags: php, forms, input

I make a order-list of items whereby the stock is below minimum.
I make a array of al the items we have, filled with 0.
Now I want to enter the number of what must be ordered.

`<td><INPUT TYPE="number" NAME="nordering[<php echo $store_central_id ?>]" SIZE="4" maxlength="4"></td>`

I see only the last number what must be ordered  and even by this not the id_store_central

I look in the database how many items i have, then i make an array `for ($i=1;$i<$number;$i++) {$nordering[$i]=0; }`
With print_r($nordering) i see only Array ( [0] => 012 ) while there are 317 items in the database.
After filling the array it is like this: Array ( [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => 0 [7] => 0 [8] => 0 [9] => 0 [10] => 0 [11] => 0 [12] => 0 [13] => 0 [14] => 0 [15] => 0 [16] => 0 [17] => 0 [18] => 0 [19] => 0 [20] => 0 [21] => 0 [22] => 0 [23] => 0 [24] => 0 [25] => 0 [26] => 0 [27] => 0 [28] => 0 [29] => 0 [30] => 0 [31] => 0 [32] => 0 [33] => 0 [34] => 0 [35] => 0 [36] => 0 [37] => 0 [38] => 0 [39] => 0 [40] => 0 [41] => 0 [42] => 0 [43] => 0 [44] => 0 [45] => 0 [46] => 0 [47] => 0 [48] => 0 [49] => 0 etc

So my solution is now to make two arrays, one with the id's and one with the numbers like:
`<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="norder_items[]" VALUE="<?PHP echo store_central_id ?>">`

`<td><INPUT TYPE="number" NAME="nordering[]" SIZE="4" maxlength="4"></td>`

Comment: Where is your array ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should do it like this:

```php
NAME="<php echo $nordering[$store_central_id]?>"
```

Just needs more information about your code.

Comment: Yes, something like that is what I want. But it is not working.When de array is 4 items, he show only one.

Comment: Are you using mysqli or pdo? Or PostgreSQL? If mysqli you needs to mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC) for retreiving an associative multiply array. Depends on your fetching data.

Comment: I use mysqli. But this is not a multiply array. I make an array with zero's and the rows in the array is the id of the items. Then if the stock is too low the row from that item id must be change from 0 to what we want to order.